# Find the highest high 5 Dates back

Tags: python, pandas

How can I store the highest high and the lowest low from the last 5 days (Dates) in a variable?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [20210201,20210202,20210203,20210201,20210204,20210205], 'Open': 
[426,428,426,440,425,431],'High': [429,429,428,450,427,433],'Low': [422,422,421,440,425,428],'Close': 
[423,430,428,445,426,432]})
print(df)
```

Result should be:

- hh = 450
- ll = 421

I did try with:

```
hh = df[df.High[::-1].cummax().eq(df.High)]
```

But I can not solve the task and have no idea how I can add a condition for last 5 Dates(highest high last 5 days).
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below working code:

```py
# first sort data by Date
df = df.sort_values("Date", ascending=False)

hh = df.iloc[:5,:]["High"].max()
ll = df.iloc[:5,:]["Low"].min()
```